# Shared Excel in a web application

Tags: javascript, html, excel, angular

My web app is angular based SPA.
I want to open a excel file using my web application.

I have a menu button/link which is mapped to a path say //192.168.10.10/sharedExcels/myExcel.xls (in-place of private IP I will be using a public IP).

So when a user clicks on the menu that file(s) is opened.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this [SheetJS js-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

this will render an excel sheet and display it as a data set